# C# Pause during foreach loop until Process.Exited

Tags: c#, process

So I have a foreach loop that goes through a DataGridView. For each row in the grid it executes a pspasswrd.exe and changes the password of a local account. How can I pause the foreach loop until the process completes before moving onto the next computer in the list?

I am not sure, I tried WaitForExit but this is not reliable since it is synchronous so it cause my program to not respond if it takes a long time. I need to utilize Process.Exited but unsure how to do this correctly.

Here is my foreach loop. Which also checks if the password was changed successfully. And inputs data into another Datagridview if it was success.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvData.Rows)
        {
            if (!row.IsNewRow && row.Cells["cIPAddress"].Value.ToString().Contains("Invalid") == false)
            {
                if (pspasswrd(row.Cells["cIPAddress"].Value.ToString(), tbTargetUser.Text, NewPassword).Contains("Password successfully changed"))
                {
                    dgvResults.Rows.Add(row.Cells["cIPAddress"].Value.ToString(), tbTargetUser.Text, NewPassword);
                    AppendNumber = AppendNumber + IncreaseNumber;
                    NewPassword = BasePassword + AppendNumber;
                }
                else
                    row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
```

But what I am unsure is that if I change my code below to use process.exited. How will it associate the password change to the computer it was successfully on. As it will be asynchronous.

```
public string pspasswrd(string ip, string user, string password)
    {
        String CD = @Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\pspasswrd.exe";
        ProcessStartInfo p = new ProcessStartInfo();
        string result = null;
        p.FileName = CD;
        p.Arguments = @"\\" + ip + " " + user + " " + password + " -accepteula";
        p.CreateNoWindow = true;
        p.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        p.RedirectStandardError = true;
        p.UseShellExecute = false;
        Process x = Process.Start(p);
        StreamReader stream = x.StandardOutput;
        result = stream.ReadToEnd();
        x.WaitForExit(2000);
        x.Close();
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: please show your code.

Comment: if you need to pause, you definitely need this off the UI thread, no matter how you tackle it

Comment: What don't you understand about using `Process.Exited`.  How is it failing to solve your problem?

Comment: @Jonesopolis No, you just need to do it asynchronously, because there is so little CPU bound work.

Comment: Code added. And clarified more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first collect all the needed information from DataGridView in a collection then run your code for executing pspasswrd.exe in a background thread looping on the collection instead of DataGridView and use WaitForExit, this will not block your UI thread.

**EDIT**

Here is the code with WaitForExit and a new thread. I believe that you will not gain much using the Exit event instead of WaitForExit other then much more complexity and deadlock scenarios:

```
 private void OnSomeUIEvent()
    {
        //In UI thread
        var ipRows = new Dictionary<string, DataGridViewRow>();
        var targetUser = ""; //tbTargetUser.Text
        var pwd = ""; //NewPassword
        var basePassword = ""; //Some value

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvData.Rows)
        {
            var ipAddress = row.Cells["cIPAddress"].Value.ToString();

            if (!row.IsNewRow && ipAddress.Contains("Invalid") == false)
            {
                ipRows.Add(ipAddress, row);
            }
        }

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {

            ChangePassword(ipRows, targetUser, pwd, basePassword);

        }).ContinueWith(t => { 

           //Do Something when task completed

        });
    }

    private void ChangePassword(Dictionary<string, DataGridViewRow> ipRows, string targetUser, string newPwd, string basePwd)
    {  //in background thread
        foreach (var ipRow in ipRows)
        {
            var pwd = newPwd;
            var basePassword = basePwd;
            var appendNumber = 0;
            var increaseNumber = 1; //some number

            if (pspasswrd(ipRow.Key, targetUser, pwd).Contains("Password successfully changed"))
            {
                dgvResults.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() =>
                {
                    dgvResults.Rows.Add(ipRow.Key, targetUser, pwd);
                }));

                appendNumber = appendNumber + increaseNumber;
                pwd = basePassword + increaseNumber;
            }
            else
            {
                dgvData.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() =>
                {
                    ipRow.Value.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
                }));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is creating a new thread just so it can spend all its time sitting around doing literally nothing.  This is extremely wasteful of resources.

Comment: @servy: Yes, but it depends, if simplicity is more important to you at the cost of creating one thread then my solution is good but if resource consumed in creating one thread is more important then Process.Exited can be used, then you will be needing a state machine instead of a simple looping to process each item in the collection.

Comment: Code added. And clarified more.